# How to wide data from dataframe

Tags: r

[I have data table whose look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Z36.png)

[I want this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9oj0.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(SubjectID) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(everything()), ~paste0(unique(.), collapse = ",")) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, ~paste0("[", ., "]"))
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  SubjectID PunchLocation NumOfPunch PunchType
      <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      <chr>    
1       102 [1,2,3,4,5]   [1,2]      [5,6,9]
```

I used this data:

```r
data <- tibble(
  SubjectID = rep(102, 12),
  PunchLocation = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4),
  NumOfPunch = c(rep(1, 10), 2, 2), 
  PunchType = c(5, 6, 5, 6, 9, 5, 6, 5, 6, 9, 5, 6)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` (with example from @Stephan).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
fun.collapse <- function(x) sprintf('[%s]', paste(unique(x), collapse=','))
dcast(data, SubjectID ~ ., 
      value.var     = c('PunchLocation', 'NumOfPunch', 'PunchType'), 
      fun.aggregate = fun.collapse)
##    SubjectID PunchLocation NumOfPunch PunchType
## 1:       102   [1,2,3,4,5]      [1,2]   [5,6,9]
```